# Task execution time higher than Timer execution time

Tags: c#, .net

I would like to clarify possible code implementaion in case if the code executing withing `timerDoJob_Elapsed` is getting longer that it should.
So all internal things  are gonna be coruppted/canceled and etc when timer fires next time.

Is there any pattern for this kind of problem?
Any clue about make it more stable?

```
private void timerDoJob_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
     VeryLongTask1();
     VeryLongTask2();
     VeryLongTask3();
}
```

Comment: Are you asking about how to cancel a task if it goes on for too long?

Comment: @SamIam No I am not. Actually a task should be done in time but next timer's iteration shouldn't destroy previous stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using [System.Timers.Timer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer(v=vs.110).aspx), turn off [AutoReset](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer.autoreset%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). Then re-enable the timer at the end of your Elapsed method.

```
private void timerDoJob_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    VeryLongTask1();
    VeryLongTask2();
    VeryLongTask3();
    mytimer.Enabled = true;
}
```

This way, the timer does not even start again until the task is complete. But make sure to wrap everything in your Elapsed method in try/catch blocks because if an unhandled exception happens there, your timer won't start again.

Another method I've used before is to use a lock in your Elapsed event:

```
var myLock = new Object();
private void timerDoJob_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    lock (myLock) {
     VeryLongTask1();
     VeryLongTask2();
     VeryLongTask3();
    }
}
```

This way, two instances of the Elapsed event cannot run at the same time. However, there is a caveat: If the task takes longer than two or more iterations of the timer, then you can have iterations adding up in the background. For example, if your timer elapses after 5 seconds, but your task takes 60 seconds to complete, by the time the first one finishes, you'll have 11 waiting.

Answer (score 1):

[`Timer.Change`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yz1c7148(v=vs.110).aspx) method giving `Timeout.Infinite` and `0` as arguments will stop the timer (from MSDN):

> If dueTime is zero (0), the callback method is invoked immediately. If
>   dueTime is Timeout.Infinite, the callback method is never invoked; the
>   timer is disabled, but can be re-enabled by calling Change and
>   specifying a positive value for dueTime.

One possible and simple but yet powerful approach is stopping the timer until the whole tasks have ended, and then, start the timer again:

```
private void timerDoJob_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
     timerDoJob.Change(Timeout.Infinite, 0);

     // Use a try-finally so if some tasks throws an exception
     // the timer will be re-enabled again anyway
     try
     {
        VeryLongTask1();
        VeryLongTask2();
        VeryLongTask3();
     }
     finally
     {
         timerDoJob.Change(0, 5000);
     }
}
```